# Not able to maintain user authentication session firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am using email & password authentication to logging in user, from my firebase dashboard i have set session expiration time to 2 months . However when i am closing my app from background and then after reopening of app i am getting var user = ref.getAuth(); as null

Does firebase does't take care of this? How to keep user logged in for a long period of time?

Below is the piece of code i am using to login user. I am using react-native

```
ref.authWithPassword({
      email    : 'username',
      password : 'password'
    }, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        navigatorReference.push({name:'myFeed'})
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
      }
    });
```

Comment: hey, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase should take care of this. Double check your configuration in the `Login & Auth` tab in your App Dashboard to make sure you have that setup properly.

You could also try passing along the configuration like so...

```
ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : 'username',
  password : 'password'
}, function(error, authData) { /* Your Code */ }, {
  remember: "default"
});
```

Comment: passing default doesn't solve the problem , i have set session length as 2 months (tried with 2 days as well) in log & auth tab.